# jquery Validate time required

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have been looking for a decent jQuery validation methodology.  I found this jsFiddle [That does something similar](http://jsfiddle.net/e2DzT/)

But I need mine to validate with AM\PM and also not be a required field for form submission.  And If I could get this to work onBlur only then that would be great.

An example acceptable time would be

```
12:00 AM
```

While there is an infinite example of unacceptable strings, this is just one of them

```
24:00
```

Now that I think about it, I would want this thing not to submit if the format is not valid, but If there is no entered time, I don't want the validator to fire.
Tried this with the jquery validator, but it is not working.

```
$().ready(function() {

$.validator.addMethod("time", function(value, element) {  
return this.optional(element) || /^(([0-1]?[0-2])|([2][0-3])):([0-5]?[0-9])(a|p)m?$/i.test(value);  
}, "Please enter a valid time.");

    $("#login").validate({
            rules: {
                    time: "required time",
            },

    });

});
```

Comment: what do you mean mean by validate am/pm. Can you give examples of accepted / not accepted values .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd point you to the indispensible jquery.validator: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation. Yeah, you'll need to take a little time to figure it out but it is time well spent. When it comes to something as universally used as validation, someone has already done the heavy lifting, no need to reinvent the wheel, if you'll excuse my overuse of metaphors.

Edit: I have had a change of opinion regarding validation. This may be somewhat tangential to the original question, but in general, I like the idea of masking/limiting fields to prevent 80-90% of user error, and the remainder can be validated via an ajax call to server-side [FluentValidation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). This strategy removes the need for jquery.validator and (most) other client-side validation. A workable and preferable approach in many situations. (Disclaimer: I am not affiliated with FluentValidation in any way other than as a user)

Comment: See the edits I just made, If I could get the Jquery Validator to Validate only if someone attempts to enter input then it would be great.

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date the example here shows how to make the input required and a date. I am assuming that if you change required: to false instead of true, it will allow empty or a valid date.

Comment: I think the OP is already using this plugin and he just needs some help writing a custom rule/method for it.

Comment: I think you're right. I don't recall the history of the question, maybe the validator snippet was added after my answer.